# CSS - box-shadow not appearing when using :before and z-index

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

My goal is to prevent box-shadow from overlapping on top of nearby elements by using `:before` and `z-index`.

But the shadow is going underneath the container of the list item that casts it because of the `z-index`.

It works fine if its parent container is just the `body`.

Is there a workaround regarding this or should I change my HTML and CSS

**HTML (PUG)**

```
div#main
  ul
    li
    li
    li
```

**CSS (Stylus)**

```
#main
  background-color lightyellow
  height 300px
  width 300px

ul
  padding 10px

  li
    background-color lightblue
    height 50px
    width 50px
    margin 10px
    position relative

  &::before
    content ''
    box-shadow 0px 0px 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    position absolute
    top 0px
    right 0px
    bottom 0px
    left 0px
    z-index -1
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using an *absolutely positioned* `pseudo` elements without setting `position: relative` to its parent, i.e. why its causing this type of issues also you haven't set some basic *CSS* rules for a better results as:

### Code Snippet

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
ul {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
ul li {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li::before {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>List01</li>
    <li>List02</li>
    <li>List03</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hmmmm, I need the shadows to come from the `li`s

Comment: I tried to change ul::before to li::before but the shadows are still overlapping the elements

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, I don't know if this is the best way to go

**HTML (PUG)**

```
ul
  li
    div.content
      span All
  li
    div.content
      span By
  li
    div.content
      span Myself
  li
    div.content
      span ANYMORE!!!
```

**CSS (STYLUS)**

```
body
  margin 15px

ul
  display inline-block

li
  width 120px
  height 50px

.content
  background-color lightyellow
  border 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.85)
  widows 100%
  height 100%
  position relative

  &::after
    box-shadow 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    position absolute
    top 0
    right 0
    left 0
    bottom 0
    content ''
    z-index -1

  span
    position absolute
    top 50%
    left 50%
    transform translate(-50%, -50%)
```